# Power series of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x+x^2+x^3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Power series of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x+x^2+x^3}$
My try was:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x+x^2+x^3}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1(x-1)}{2}\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
Now using the infinite geometric sum I got:
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-x)^n-\frac{1}{2}(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-x^2)^n=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty[(-1)^nx^n-(-1)^nx^{2n+1}+(-1)^nx^{2n}]$$

The problem that I don't know if my moves are valid, and moreover, I don't know how to make it look as Power series.

Comment: You changed $(x-1)$ to $(1-x)$ in the second sum.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369435/find-expansion-around-x-0-0-into-power-series-and-find-a-radius-of-convergence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT** Observing that $$
\frac{1}{1-y}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty y^k
$$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x+x^2+x^3}=\frac{1-x}{1-x^4}=(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{4k}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$ \frac{1-x}{1-x^4}   $$

=======

Answer (score 2):

You could write it as 
$$ \dfrac{1-x}{1-x^4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$
where $$a_n = \cases{1 & if $n \equiv 0 \mod 4$\cr
                    -1 & if $n \equiv 1 \mod 4$\cr
                     0 & otherwise}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your method will work (Add the first $3$ equations to get the fourth.)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1+x} &=& 1  & -x &  +x^2 & -x^3  & +x^4 &  -x^5 & +x^6 & -x^7 & +x^8 &+ \cdots \\
\frac{ \frac{1}{2}}{1+x^2} &=&  1  &    & -x^2 &       & +x^4 &       & -x^6 &      & +x^8 &+ \cdots \\
\frac{-\frac{1}{2}x}{1+x^2} &=&    & -x  &      & +x^3  &      &  -x^5 &      & +x^7 &   &+ \cdots \\
\frac{1}{1+x+x^2+x^3} &=& 1  & -x &   &    & +x^4 &  -x^5 &   &   & +x^8 &+ \cdots \\
\end{eqnarray*}
But as alexjo points out, there is an easier way.